# How can I set a vector in C++ and all its data at the same time?

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote some JavaScript code but now I want to translate it to C++ because of perfomance, but my knowledge of C++ is low.

In JavaScript I can do:

```
var arr=[[['à','á'],['è','é'],['ì','í'],['ò','ó'],['ù','ú']],['a','e','i','o','u']];
```

How can I do something like that in C++?
Must I do

```
vector<vector<char>> arr;
```

and then set each element manually?

```
arr[0][0]='à';
arr[0][1]='á';
...
```

Comment: FYI: C++'s `char` type is not good for Unicode symbols.

Comment: But works fine with ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's at least a bit more work unless you have C++11, which adds the possibility of constructors taking an initializer list:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> arr {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd', 'e'}, {'f'}};
```

You might also consider replacing `std::vector<char>` with `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast.I didn't know C++11. Do you know how can I use it in Dev-C++?

Comment: @Oriol, IIRC Dev-C++'s version of GCC is pretty old. If it's too old, you'll have to upgrade it (my personal favourite is http://nuwen.net/mingw.html). Also, you must compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`. As for the IDE, [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is a good step up from Dev-C++. I'm familiar with upgrading GCC on there; all I have to do is replace the `MinGW` folder with the new one.

Comment: Thanks!
I have installed minGW 64 bits (minGW 32 bits threw errors) and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for C++11

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> var arr={{'à','á'},{'è','é'},{'ì','í'},{'ò','ó'},{'ù','ú'},{'a','e','i','o','u'}};
// Note it is changed from the original I removed one level of nesting from part of the array.
```

If you are using C++03.
Then you need to change things slightly.

```
std::string var[] = {"àá'", "èé", "ìí", "òó", "ùú", "aeiou"};
```

The types have changes but it has the same affect and access to the object `var` is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `std::vector< std::pair< char, char > >`.

Note, that you cannot use `operator[]`(ie. call `arr[0]` or `arr[0][0]` on an empty vector (since the requested elements are not there, you access invalid memory which (hopefully) will crash your program). Add elements to a vector with `push_back(...)`:

```
vector< pair< char, char > > arr;
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'à','á' ) );
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'è','é' ) );
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'ì','í' ) );
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'ò','ó' ) );
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'ò','ó' ) );
arr.push_back( make_pair( 'ù','ú' ) );
```

Depending on what you want to do, `std::map< char, char >` might be useful for you as well. It will allow you to access elements using the first type as a key, eg.

```
std::map<char, char > mymap;
mymap['à'] = 'á';
// will print "Element à = à"
cout << "Element à = " <<  mymap['à']  << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't initialize a vector as an array. However, you can initialize a vector *with* an array. For a single vector:

```
static const int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

Initializing a vector of vectors is a little tricky, but you can do it in a cycle either like above, or like this: (pseudocode):

```
for( int i =0; i < something; i++ )//the outer vector
{
    vector.pushBack( std::vector<int> );
    for( int j =0; j < somethingElse; j++)
        vector[i].push_back(j);
}
```

Comment: Or better, `std::vector<int> vec(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`

Comment: @SethCarnegie, If you have C++11, you might as well use my solution. This fits the bill perfectly for C++03.

Comment: @chris are `begin` and `end` C++11 only? I thought C++03 had references to arrays too. If it's just that they don't come in `std` then you can write your own.

Comment: @chris even if you use C++03, it pays to have your own `begin` and `end` for arrays.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin. True, it's possible to make your own, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes and you can also make them work for STL containers as well (because if the type provides a `iterator` typedef then you don't need `decltype`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet using c++0x:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector< vector<char> > v = { {'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'} };
    for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        cout <<"Subvector: ";
        for (unsigned j=0; j<v[i].size(); j++)
            cout << v[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with g++ -std=c++0x

Comment: C++11 has [ranged-based for loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop) you can use to make going through it easier.